# How to configurate the home client in dbeaver for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I'm am tryng to import a database, however i'm getting this message :

> Client home is not specified for connection

I guess that i have to configurate the cliente, however i dont't know how to fill these form, i've already tried, putting in the forms: /etc/postgresql/13/main, but does not work.

[image: image of dbeaver]

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and use `psql`.

Comment: I've get rid of snap and used deb version, but still I'm unable to select "psql" binary it's grayed out

Comment: @holms I guess you need to select the containing folder, not the binary itself

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I was getting the error `native client is not specified for connection` when trying to export a database. In Terminal, ran the command `which postgres` resulting in `/opt/homebrew/bin/postgres`.  Then in Dbeaver went to the database and right clicked > Edit Connection > Edit Driver Settings > choose the Native Client tab > Add Home > choose Mac HD > once that comes up hit `Command + Shift + .` to unhide the hidden folders.  Then navigate to `opt/homebrew/bin`  and click Open.  It will find the postgres info it needs and add the home.  Click OK > OK to close the pop-ups.  Now I can do the export.

Comment: thanks for tip ->  Command + Shift + .

Answer (score 10):

Actually the issue was the snap version of DBeaver. You can't access directories outside your snap home folder(in this case Dbeaver Snap home folder). So I reverted back to APT version of DBeaver using  [this link](https://dbeaver.io/files/dbeaver-ce_latest_amd64.deb) (for debain based version) and it worked like a charm.

So you just remove your snap version of DBeaver and install the official package from [their website](https://dbeaver.io/download/) for your OS and you should be able to load the client without any issue.

Comment: I installed via flatpak (not snap) and had the same problem as OP. I uninstalled flatpak DBeaver and use @rabra 's suggestion to just install with the .deb package. This solution worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I know its late.

- Just install the `pgsql` from apt. you can follow this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-postgresql-on-ubuntu-20-04-quickstart) to install.
- Then setup client as: `/usr/lib/postgresql/XX/` 
  where `XX` is the version of the pgsql you installed.

Comment: The following error occursError executing process
  `Utility 'pg_dump' not found in client home '/usr/share/postgresql/15' (/usr/share/postgresql/15)`

Answer (score 5):

There's a pretty lengthy discussion about this topic here:
https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/988

I couldn't manage to do it, because my dbeaver didnt have the right to get into /usr/bin and I couldn't open it in sudo from the terminal. I gave up and used psql instead.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have Postgresql installed, open a terminal and type in

`$ which psql`

It will respond something like:

`/usr/bin/psql`

Then Open Dbeaver -> open your connection -> open Databases -> right  -> Select Dump database / Restore database

A windows will pop up, at the *Bottom left*, click on **Local Client**

Another windows will pop up, select **Browse**

In the next window, click **Add Home**

Navigate to the output location of postgres `/usr/bin` Then click Open
and click on something so the window fills in the fields. Click OK -> OK.

You should be good to Dump or Restore your database.

Answer (score 2):

I would just add to @Chnikki's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73393070/22592482) (which worked for me very well) that **one should not attempt to create a new** connection with that Homebrew installation.

This is because a new connection looks for a (Java) driver class which requires a `jar` file. [That Homebrew installation](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/postgresql@12) does not seem to include a `jar` file.

Instead, **edit** the existing DBeaver (CE, 23.2.1) connection:

1. Right-click > Edit Connection
2. Connection settings (tab) > Driver Settings (button)
3. Edit Driver 'PostgreSQL' dialog > Native Client (tab)
4. Add Home (button)  >  OK

Answer (score 1):

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:serge-rider/dbeaver-ce
2. sudo apt update

this query works for me